# Javascript and SOAP (CUCM)

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, cucm

I'm using this code (http://blog.darrenparkinson.uk/2014/04/accessing-cisco-administrative-xml-axl.html) to make connection with CUCM.
But, this code returns the XML in console. I need a XML file or .CSV file for open in Excel.
How can I do this?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a list of all the Route Patterns on the Call Manager? etc. I guess this should help:

https://medium.com/@chandupriya93/xml-to-excel-conversion-using-node-js-d70296ba3bea

This uses an xml2js and json2xls module to parse the XML file into a JSON file and finally convert into XLS.

Hope this helps.

Ank

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is [camaro](https://npmjs.com/package/camaro). You can take the element you want as an array easy. then convert that to `csv`

You can see the sample in that package